# Sending info back and forth via links and not using session() (php and html)

Tags: php, html

Okey, so i have 2 html pages and 2 php pages.

The both html pages contains links with name and value arguments depending on which one you click on.

What im trying to accomplish is:

1. you click on a link (with a name/value pair) on the first html page
2. This should take you to the other html page and the name/value pair which you clicked on in the first page should be transfered to this page.
3. All of this should be done using php.

I haven't gotten this to work yet and i dont understand why my solution isn't working. Can you please have a look?

Code below:

First HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
  <title>doc1</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
  <a href="doc1.php?namn=filip">namn</a><br>
  <a href="doc1.php?namn=fellman">namn</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

First PHP page:

```html
<?php

 $namn = $_GET["namn"];
 
 $html = file_get_contents("doc2.html");
 
 $rep = substr_replace('doc2.php?namn=', $namn, 14);
 
 $html = str_replace('---$namn---', $rep, $html);
 
 echo $html;
 
?>
```

Second HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
  <title>doc2</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
  <a href="doc2.php?land=finland">land</a><br>
  <a href="doc2.php?land=sverige">land</a>
  <a href="---$namn---" style="display:none">namn</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Second PHP page:

```html
<?php
 
 header("Content-Type: text/plain");
 
 echo "namn: " . $_GET["namn"]."\n";
 echo "land: " . $_GET["land"];
 
?>
```

If you have a simpler or easier solution i would be happy to know.

If i look in the code on my browser i see that the correct data is transferd and replaced, but the "namn" variable is undefined it says.. see error code below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: namn in C:\Apache24\htdocs\WEB-SERVER\4.1.1 Information inbakad i länkar\doc2.php on line 5
```

namn: land: sverige

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get two values from the query string:

```
echo "namn: " . $_GET["namn"]."\n";
echo "land: " . $_GET["land"];
```

But you don't have any one request which contains *both* of those values.  You have two different links which each contain *one* of the values:

```
<a href="doc2.php?land=sverige">land</a>
<a href="doc2.php?namn=filip" style="display:none">namn</a>
```

(One of which is styled to not even be displayed...)

So whichever of those two different links you click one, *one* of the *two* values won't be set.

You'd need a single link with *both* values:

```
<a href="doc2.php?namn=filip&land=sverige">land</a>
```

So your code, before PHP replaces the text, might look something like this:

```
<a href="doc2.php?---$namn---&land=sverige">land</a>
```

Of course you'll also need to modify your PHP string replacing logic to address the new string format.  Your approach is a little manual on that, so you'll have to tinker with it a bit and observe the actual output result to adjust as needed.  But you should get the idea.

There's a variety of ways to carry over the value, to modify the strings, considerations for how to URL-encode values, etc.  But the fundamental concept at the very least is that the URL needs *both* values, not just one of them.

Basically, the server doesn't store information from previous requests.  You either need to store it somewhere (such as session state) *or* include the information on the subsequent request, such as a query string value in the URL.